# Python. Using inheritance to write code to find price of car from dealership

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am trying to use inheritance to write a program which goal is to determine the price of a vehicle in a car lot as $4,000×number of wheels a vehicle has. You also buy vehicles. You offer a flat rate -10% of the miles driven on the vehicle. The flat rates are: for cars $7,500, for trucks: $9,000.
An example of the output should be:

```
>>> x=Car(4, 12000,'Mazda','CX5,2017,'Automatic','Red')
>>> y=Truck(7,8,15000,'Ford','Engine',1987)
>>> x.sale_price()
16000
>>> x.purchase_price()
6300.0
>>> x.getDescription()
'Mazda CX5 2017 -Red, 12000 miles >>> $16000'
>>> x.sell()
>>> x.sale_price()
0.0
>>> x.sell()
This item has been sold
>>> y.sale_price()
32000
>>> y.purchase_price()
7500.0
>>> y.getDescription()
'Ford Engine 1987, 15000 miles -7 seats >>> $32000'
>>> y.sell()
>>> y.sell()
This item has been sold
>>> y.sale_price()
0.0
```

I wrote the following code:

```
class Car:
   def __init__(self, wheels, miles, make, model, year):
      self.wheels = wheels
      self.miles = miles
      self.make = make
      self.model = model
      self.year = year
      self.sold_on = False

   def sell(self):
      if self.sold_on == True:
         print('This item has been sold')
      else:
         self.sold_on = True  

   def sale_price(self):
      if self.sold_on:
         return 0.0
      return 4000 * self.wheels 

   def purchase_price(self):
      return self.flat_rate - (0.10 * self.miles)

class Car(Car, object):
   def __init__(self, wheels, miles, make, model, year, gear, color):
      super(Car, self).__init__(wheels, miles, make, model, year)  
      self.gear = gear
      self.color = color
      self.flat_rate = 7500
   def getDescription(self):
      sale_price = self.sale_price()
      return '{} {} {} - {}, {} miles >>> ${}'.format(self.make, self.model, self.year, self.color, self.miles, sale_price)  

class Truck(Car, object):
   def __init__(self, wheels, miles, make, model, year, seats):
      super(Truck, self).__init__(wheels, miles, make, model, year)  
      self.seats = seats
      self.flat_rate = 9000

   def sale_price(self):
      if self.sold_on:
         return 0.0
      return 4000    

   def getDescription(self):
      sale_price = self.sale_price()
      return '{} {} {}, {} miles - {} seats >>> ${}'.format(self.make, self.model, self.year, self.miles, self.seats, sale_price)
```

I am having an issue obtaining the desired output. I feel my logic is right. I am getting error messages saying "Duplicate bases for the class truck", "class Car already defined". I don't know how I can alter my code to eliminate these. Thank you for any help

Comment: You can't use the same class name twice `Car(Car, object)`, also, the base class should inherit from `object`, but the subclasses don't need to

Comment: @BrendanAbel you don't need to inherit from object in python3 at all.

Comment: Regarding inheriting from object: neither of the above commenters are wrong.  It's probably a good idea to have your base class inherit from object, but it is not necessary.  If you choose to do so, the sub-classes should not inherit from it as well.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots What do you mean by have a base class inherit from an object. Do you mean to have the "Class car" inherit from the next class?

Comment: @BrendanAbel What should I do then?

Comment: Have the first `Car` class inherit from `object` (and I suggest changing the name to `Vehicle`, you need to change the name of one of the `Car` classes) and then any class inheriting from `Vehicle` will automatically inherit all properties of `object` as well

Comment: But Brendan is right, you don't need to have the `Vehicle` class inherit from any class at all

Comment: @ChootsMagoots  Sorry for the many questions this is the first time I ever used inheritance. Are you saying I could eliminate the second class?

Comment: See my answer to the top question.  No, I'm not saying you should eliminate the second class.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Vehicle(object):
    # Things

class Car(Vehicle):
    # other things

class Truck(Vehicle):
    # yet more things
```